# unit testing a java method which only calls other methods in a chain of lambda expressions

Tags: java, unit-testing, lambda

Consider java method:

```
    public result method(Optional<T> param) {
       return param.flatmap(SomeOtherClass::method1)
                   .flatmap(SomeOtherClass::method2)
                   .orElseThrow(new RuntimeException("   "))
    }
```

Does it really make sense to unit test **method**? My argument is that since, method1 is only calling lambda expressions and really doing nothing, it makes no sense.
Please correct if I am mistaken here. Possibly provide some code sample which unit tests covering multiple cases (using Mocks is fine )

Comment: The reason why this is difficult is the two static methods in SomeOtherClass.  Is there any way you could replace these with non-static methods, and call them on a particular object from within your class?  Then you'd be able to stub them out, and actually write a decent test.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call throwing an exception if your mappings don't come across as "doing nothing".

You *definitely* want to test this method in at least two cases:

- What happens with successful mappings
- What happens with *un*successful mappings

I can't provide source for you to utilize since I have no idea how to map between `Object` and `Object`.

Comment: Exception is being thrown in the case last flatmap returns empty optional. Which is requirement specification of the method.

Comment: ...And that's something you'd want to test, right?  Given that it's a requirement and all.

Comment: yeah :). But it is more of responsibility of Optional. Which means Optional will throw an exception if it does not have a value. method in question will have no control over exception. any way could you help me with a test which covers exception scenario. mocking is fine.

Comment: Yes, but if that optional returns empty and throws that exception, **that will be emanating from `method` because `method` _elected_ to throw.**  Again, that is something that you need to test and validate against your data set.